# Using the :target selector to affect an unrelated DIV (without Javascript)?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to use the `:target` CSS selector to affect another DIV? For example, when a user visits `http://website.com/#button` could you style the .photo element if the elements were structured as below?

```
<div class="gallery">
  <ul>
   <li class="photo">
   <li class="photo">
  </ul>
<div>
<div id="button">Button Text</div>
```

Comment: You will usually be able to, but in this case you can't because `#button` comes after `.gallery`, and you can't walk backwards with sibling selectors.

Answer (score 3):

`:target` checks the hash part of the url and looks for matching a `id` on an element. So yes, you can affect another element, but it needs an `id` that matches the current hash part. Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/Tetaxa/egF3d/

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! What if I was trying to create an active (or rather "selected") state for the anchor elements in this example while maintaining the functionality? http://jsfiddle.net/g7Yzu/10/

Comment: You want to be able to have several elements selected at any one time? I don't think it can be done in pure CSS.

Comment: Well, I just need one element selected. I was hoping some sort of combinator would do the trick, but have been unable to get that to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can affect multiple elements, but they'll all have to be related to the element that's the target.  The easiest way to do this is to put the `id` on a wrapper element:

```
<div id="gallery1">
    <div class="gallery">
      <ul>
          <li class="photo">Photo</li>
          <li class="photo">Photo</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="gallery2">
    <div class="gallery">
      <ul>
          <li class="photo">Photo</li>
          <li class="photo">Photo</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#gallery1">Gallery 1</a>|<a href="#gallery2">Gallery 2</a>
```

Then you can have rules like this:

```
.gallery {
    //rules for when gallery is not the target
}
:target .gallery {
    //rules for when the gallery is the target
}
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/JeEXm/).